# How are these MySQL classes able to link?

Tags: c++, mysql, gcc, linker, g++

Within the implementation of the builtin MySQL storage engines, there exist classes with the following structure:

```cpp
// omitting lots of code across several files
class handler {
   protected:
      virtual void notify_table_changed();
};

void handler::notify_table_changed() {
   // implementation
}

class ha_innopart : public handler {
   void notify_table_changed();
};

// NB: no implementation for ha_innopart!
```

As I understand things, this should give a link error since `ha_innopart` will be missing a vtable entry for `notify_table_changed()`. This is [supported by the gcc FAQ](https://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#vtables).

Links to the MySQL classes in question:

- `handler.h`: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/67d52e7c7a1a23424e39273cbb6f5f9d56fda8d1/sql/handler.h#L3518-L3523
- `handler.cc`: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/67d52e7c7a1a23424e39273cbb6f5f9d56fda8d1/sql/handler.cc#L4736-L4744
- `ha_innopart.h`: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/67d52e7c7a1a23424e39273cbb6f5f9d56fda8d1/storage/innobase/handler/ha_innopart.h#L306-L307

The following code reproduces the problem, as I see it:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
   public:
      virtual int foo();
};

class B : public A {
   public:
      int foo();               // Will work by commenting out this line...
};

int A::foo() { return 42; }
// int B::foo() { return 24; } // ...or uncommenting this line.

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   B b;
   ::printf("%d\n", b.foo());
}
```

Compiling this gives:

```
$ g++ test.cc -o test && ./test
/tmp/ccAiCHry.o: In function `main':
test.cc:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `B::foo()'
/tmp/ccAiCHry.o: In function `B::B()':
test.cc:(.text._ZN1BC2Ev[_ZN1BC5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for B'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As written in the comments above, the issue can be resolved by commenting out `B`'s declaration of `foo()` or by supplying an implementation of `foo()` for `B`. The output of those cases, respectively, is:

```
$ !!
g++ test.cc -o test && ./test
42
$ !!
g++ test.cc -o test && ./test
24
```

So, how is it that MySQL doesn't implement `ha_innopart::notify_table_changed()` and is still able to compile and link without error?

Comment: it's either not used or it is in a library.  Take a program that uses it, look at the libraries you link it with, and go through the symbols in the libraries until you find it.  something like "nm" will help you https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the implementation for `ha_innopart` is broken out over several files, and the implementation does exist:

- `handler0alter.cc`: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/67d52e7c7a1a23424e39273cbb6f5f9d56fda8d1/storage/innobase/handler/handler0alter.cc#L8927-L8938

I found the implementation while searching for uses.

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=notify_table_changed